# how to include special character into the string array.while splitting the string using special character of Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex

```
String s = "select from(select * LEAF_CATEG_ID,a.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,a.HARD_BOUNCE_TYPE";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String[] parts=p.split(s);

    for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
        System.out.println("After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:"+parts[i]);

    }
```

**The expectation output from me is:**

```
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:select
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:from
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:(
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:select
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:*
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:LEAF
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:_
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:CATEG
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:_
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:ID
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:,
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:a
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:.
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:FROM
```

> **But what I get is:**

```
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:select
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:from
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:select
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:LEAF
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:CATEG
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:ID
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:a
After finding special characters i am able to split the characters:FROM
```

> I want to split the above string into String array of object including the special characters but my current code is not including the special character,its skipping the special character 
>   Please help me out,Thanks in advance....

Comment: Are you sure of the expected output? Some spaces are included and some are excluded. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/LL7PjB) (`Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?<=(?:_|[^a-z0-9]))|(?=(?:_|[^a-z0-9]))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`) that should be working for you IMHO (splitting out more elements than you expect). If it does not, please clarify.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thanks for your comment. I am not considering spaces there won't be a space in the string,there only a special characters ,where i want to split and save it in the string array including the special characters too.

Comment: You do have a space in the expected output right above `LEAF`. Does my code work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev: Its work for me thanks for your help.

Comment: @stribizhev:does the above solutions which you shared with me will work for all type of special character like _ - , * ( ) & ^ % $ # @ ! ~ ' " ? / .

Comment: It will. Actually, it dawned upon me that alternation is not necessary in `(?:_|[^a-z0-9])`, `_` is actually matched with `[^a-z0-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split and keep the delimiters in Java, you need to use *lookarounds*:  a combination of a lookahead and a lookbehind with the delimiter of your choice.

The **delimiter** in your case is *any character other than an ASCII letter or digit*. It can be achieved with

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?<=[^a-z0-9])|(?=[^a-z0-9])",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Note that you do not need `[A-Z]` as you are using a `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/LL7PjB) and here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ4wC8/2).

The regex matches two empty locations that are

- `(?<=[^a-z0-9])` - preceded with a character other than `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`
- `(?=[^a-z0-9])` - followed by a character other than `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`.

Comment: how can i exclude a particular special character "_"  from the above Pattern.I don't want to split for the underscore special character but i want to keep it as it is.I want to split the string with remaining special character which you suggested me in the above Pattern. Thanks

Comment: Excluding some character here means adding it to the negated character class: [`"(?<=[^_a-z0-9])|(?=[^_a-z0-9])"`](https://regex101.com/r/gZ4wC8/3).

Comment: I have one more scenario in my project, I am pasting the code.My requirement is i want to add the semicolon to the string when ever it is splitting the string but the semicolon is adding to next string ,here is the code  String sampleContent="hello ; hai ;  come fast ;";                                        String SQLScripts[] = sampleContent.split("(?=\\;)",-1); after looping in the for loop i am getting the out put as===>: OUTPUT: hello ,OUTPUT:  ; hai ,OUTPUT: ;  come fast ,OUTPUT:  ; But i want semicolon has to be added to the first splitting string only Like : hello; hai;